# Reorganizing controller files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-api, laravel-controller

In Laravel, I can't find my controller after rearranging the file and folder structure in `app/http/controller`. I wanted to organize my controller files due to their large number. Here's how it looks now.

[image]

Then, when I want to use the following API:

```
Route::post('/jadwal-dokter', [DokterController::class, 'jadwaldokterterpilih']);
```

I'm getting this response:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\DokterController] does not exist.

This is how I connect my `api.php` to my controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\DetailPasienController;
use App\Http\Controllers\dokter\DokterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\JadwalPoliController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PasienController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PoliController;
use App\Models\jadwal_poli;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

But when i change the `DokterController` directory to

```
use App\Http\Controllers\DokterController;
```

it can't detect my controller and it look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

your namespaces in the begining of the controller file should match the herirechy of the data sturcture

it should implement [PSR-4 autoloading standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

check [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/structure#the-app-directory) for more details

so namespace for DokterController should be

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\dokter;
```

and the use should be:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\docker\DokterController;
```

further try to refactor your code in your route file . Instead of calling controller during defining each route separately you should use

```
 Route::controller(controllername::class)->group(function(){
     Route::get('routeurl','controllerMethodToCallForThisRoute');
})
```

Comment: what if im using laravel 10?

Comment: same thing:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/structure#the-app-directory